# Powershell verbose output for chained exceptions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I'm new to powershell and troubleshooting an issue with one of our custom cmdlets. By default, all exceptions thrown within the cmdlet have minimum information, no stack trace and no info on chained exceptions. Is there a way to enable verbose output of exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a neat function that I've stolen from someone on the 'net :). I have it in my profile and will happily spread it further:

```
#Get detailed information on an error
function Resolve-Error ($ErrorRecord=$Error[0])
{
   $ErrorRecord | Format-List * -Force
   $ErrorRecord.InvocationInfo |Format-List *
   $Exception = $ErrorRecord.Exception
   for ($i = 0; $Exception; $i++, ($Exception = $Exception.InnerException))
   {   "$i" * 80
       $Exception |Format-List * -Force
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, found the original blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/07/resolve-error.aspx. Do you know what `"$i" * 80` line does? And also I get an exception when I call this function: `Missing function body in function declaration`

Comment: Thanks for finding the original for me. `"$i" * 80` seems simply to be a formatting, to separate the exceptions. But the `missing function body`is kind of strange; it is the most recent error though so the function does what it should.

Comment: I removed the function parameter `$ErrorRecord=$Error[0]` and replaced `$ErrorRecord` with `$Error[0]` inside the function body and everything worked fine.

Comment: [Kateroh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/439213) - I think the `$ErrorRecord=$Error[0]` line is to isolate the error into a user variable, before another error pushes the current `$Error[0]` to `$Error[1]`, or somewhere else down the "line".

Comment: `$ErrorRecord=$Error[0]` is a defaulted value so that in the event of no argument you will still have a valid value to use in the function.

Comment: You are better off dumping the exception as is, since its `ToString` method will iterate over inner exceptions for you, among other things (like iterating all internal exceptions inside an `AggregateException`).

Answer (score 4):

the $error collection contains a live list of all unhandled exceptions thrown in the current session. The last exception is at $error[0]. A good technique to do something like this to capture the error as soon as possible:

```
ps> invoke-something
error: ...
ps> $e = $error[0]
```

Explore $e with get-member.

Comment: "Explore $e with get-member" - how to do this would be a great addition to your answer

Answer (score 4):

I've used this technique to get nested error objects:

```
$error[0]|format-list -force
```

Comment: Something else to understand, error records have a default formatting of the red message that you see when the error occurs.  You need to turn it into something else to see everything.